# Web-scraping for td data

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Can someone explain to me why my code is not picking up the PriorSettle td's? I am getting the months but for whatever reason the PrioSettle column is not showing up.

```
lc_result={}

url = "http://www.cmegroup.com/trading/agricultural/livestock/live-cattle.html"

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.set_window_size(2,2)
driver.get(url) #this will go the the actual url listed
print('     Live Cattle Futures'+localtime.center(50))
table = driver.find_element_by_id('quotesFuturesProductTable1')
for row in table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')[2:]:
    month=row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')[0].text  
    priorsettle=row.find_elements_by_tag_name('td')[4].text

    print month, priorsettle
    lc_result[month]=[priorsettle]

driver.close()
print(str(date.today()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait for the table to load. Simply adding a delay made it work for me:

```
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(3)

table = driver.find_element_by_id('quotesFuturesProductTable1')
...
```

Prints:

```
DEC 2014 168.025
FEB 2015 166.900
APR 2015 164.775
JUN 2015 154.800
AUG 2015 152.900
OCT 2015 154.100
DEC 2015 154.250
FEB 2016 153.850
APR 2016 0.000
```

FYI, implicit timeouts using `time.sleep()` is not a reliable and recommended way to wait for elements. `Selenium` has built-in [`Waits`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/waits.html) mechanism.